# How to count the number of faces detected in live video by openCV using python?

Tags: python, opencv

I need to count the number of faces in a video taken from webcam. For example, if I am standing in front of the camera then count=1, now if any other person is detected then count=2, if another person is detected then the count should be 3.

I am using frontal_face_haarcascade.xml by opencv in python. I can detect faces in frame and then increase the count, but what's happening is that the count is increasing as the number of frames. So, even if 1 person was detected standing for 10 sec, it shows count as some '67'.

How can I overcome this problem?

This is the code:

```
import cv2

import sys

cascPath = sys.argv[1]

faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)


video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = video_capture.read()

gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
    gray,
    scaleFactor=1.1,
    minNeighbors=5,
    minSize=(30, 30)
)

# Draw a rectangle around the faces
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)


if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

# Display the resulting frame
cv2.imshow('Video', frame)


video_capture.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: can you post the code you have used?

Comment: @JeruLuke Added the code

Comment: google for _"tracking"_

Answer (score -1):

```
idx=0
while(True):
  ret, frame = video_capture.read()

  gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

  faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
    gray,
    scaleFactor=1.1,
    minNeighbors=5,
    minSize=(30, 30)
  )

  # Draw a rectangle around the faces
  for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
      cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
      idx += 1
      print (idx)


  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
      break

  # Display the resulting frame
  cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cascPath)

video_capture  =cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while(True):
    idx=0

    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
        gray,
        scaleFactor=1.1,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(30, 30)
    )
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
        idx += 1
        print (idx)
        cv2.putText(frame,str(idx),(x,y+h),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,.7,(150,150,0),2)


    cv2.imshow('img',frame)
    if(cv2.waitKey(1)==ord('q')):
        break

frame.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: if  ` cv2.putText ` make error then you use different version of opencv so tell me to update the code

Comment: Please add some explanation. What was the issue in the question? How does you answer solves that problem? Code dumps are not really much useful... And why did you post 2 answers? (btw, none of them solves the problem)

Comment: i didn't understand your question so i add two possible  answers and i want to know if you use opencv 2 or opencv 3

Comment: That's not my question ;)

Comment: It just shows how many faces are being detected currently, I need the count to increase everytime another face is detected.